# Something happened on our end. Error code 0x87E10BC6

Tags: windows-10-v1909, wsl2

I'm facing the below error when trying to open "Ubuntu 20.04" from the Windows 10 Start menu to finish the WSL2 installation setup. I also found that it's not limited to only the WSL2 installation, and everything which was required to get/connect to Microsoft Store to downloading/installing it keeps getting the same error.

> Something happened on our end. Error code 0x87E10BC6

I tried to google it as well as [this Microsoft thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/something-happened-on-our-end-error-code/c581ef02-aa05-4c04-962e-9bc4c90b0d32), but no solution worked out. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:
I managed to fix it by changing my region to "United States".

Comment: Why is it that way then?